# Is it necessary to repeat name in Calling Function?

Tags: excel, quantlib, vba

Example:

`“qlBlackConstantVol”` with `"blackConstantVol"`:

```
blackVolId = Application.Run("qlBlackConstantVol", _

"blackConstantVol", 35932, "Target", 0.2, "Actual/365 (Fixed)")
```

If so, why do they repeat the name in every function, except in this one:

```
blackScholesId = Application.Run( _

"qlGeneralizedBlackScholesProcess", "blackScholes", _

blackVolId, 36, "Actual/365 (Fixed)", 35932, 0.06, 0)
```

Comment: First: this seems like a question you can answer on your own, through trial & error. I suspect the answer is technically "no", but effectively: "Yes", it's necessary to pass the arguments as you're doing presently. More importantly I think you're misunderstanding the code, because you're not passing the name twice, you're only passing the name once. Everything else is an argument to the function being called.

Comment: @DavidZemens Is it Correct that the name of the function is irrelevant, and doesn't reflect any constraint on the use of Application.Run ?

Comment: @Ester The name of the function needs to be passed to `Application.Run` so it is not irrelevant. The fact that this particular function takes a string argument and one of the values of that string happens to be similar to the name of the function is a quirk of that particular function and has nothing to do with `Application.Run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary to pass the arguments as you're doing presently but I think you're misunderstanding the code, because you're not passing the name twice, you're only passing the name once.

```
blackVolId = Application.Run("qlBlackConstantVol", _
    "blackConstantVol", 35932, "Target", 0.2, "Actual/365 (Fixed)")
```

However, there is nothing about `Application.Run` that requires passing the name twice (and if you look closely, you'll see that is not in fact what you're doing, you're passing the name, and some other arbitrary but similar `String`):

In the above context, `"qlBlackConstantVol"` is the procedure to run, whereas `"blackConstantVol"` is just a String argument that is an input to the function `qlBlackConstantVol`.

Without seeing the function body, it's impossible to say what `"blackConstantVol"` is used for, and whether it's "arbitrary" so without more detail, I would say you should not alter it unless you know what you're doing and why.

> Is it Correct that the name of the function is irrelevant, and doesn't reflect any constraint on the use of `Application.Run` ?

The name itself imposes constraints on the subsequent args list, so while the name is not itself a constraint (i.e., you can pass any function name provided it's a valid/accessible function), it does impose constraints (the args list must be valid for that function). Confusing?

## Let's unpack `Application.Run`:

[Application.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-run-method-excel) has the following signature:

> `expression . Run( Macro , Arg1 , Arg2 , Arg3 , Arg4 , Arg5 , Arg6 ,
>   Arg7 , Arg8 , Arg9 , Arg10 , Arg11 , Arg12 , Arg13 , Arg14 , Arg15 ,
>   Arg16 , Arg17 , Arg18 , Arg19 , Arg20 , Arg21 , Arg22 , Arg23 , Arg24
>   , Arg25 , Arg26 , Arg27 , Arg28 , Arg29 , Arg30 )`

The first argument `Macro` is optional (!) and represents:

> The macro to run. This can be either a string with the macro name, a
>   Range object indicating where the function is, or a register ID for a
>   registered DLL (XLL) function. If a string is used, the string will be
>   evaluated in the context of the active sheet.

The remaining arguments each represent:

> An argument that should be passed to the function.

## How Does Application.Run work?

Assume you have 2 subroutines with required arguments such as:

```
Sub foo(i As Long, b As Boolean, s As String)
Static counter As Long
counter = counter + i
    If b Then MsgBox ("Count: " & counter & ". " & s)
End Sub

Sub bar(i As Long)
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```

In order to invoke `foo` this from `Application.Run`, you need to pass it as such:

```
Application.Run("foo", _some_long_integer_value, _a_boolean_value, _a_string_value)
```

## What Happens if you pass the wrong type or number of arguments?

If you don't pass it enough arguments, you'll get an error:

```
Application.Run("foo", 90210)
```

[image]

If you pass too many arguments (`bar` only takes a single parameter), you'll get an error:

```
Application.Run("bar", 6, True, "hello")
```

[image]

If you pass it arguments of the wrong type, you'll get an error:

```
Application.Run("bar", "Blue")
```

[image]

If you pass it impossible arguments that cannot be evaluated (such as an invalid `Range` specification), you'll get the 1004 error:

```
Application.Run("foo", True, Range("A1:A-10"))
```

[image]

There are probably more possible errors you might get when using this method, the above were easy enough to illustrate but I don't claim they are an exhaustive list.

Of course, you can call most any function/sub this way (with some caveats: it must be in scope, the args list depends on the function to be `Run`, etc.), so in that sense it doesn't strictly matter what you pass for `Macro` as long as the subsequent parameters match the function signature.

Comment: Nice, complete answer (+1)

Comment: Why Does this Don't Work ? "" sPlainVanillaPayoff = Application.Run("qlPlainVanillaPayoff", "PlainVanillaPayoff", "Call", 100)
"EuropeanExercise", 43449)  ""

Comment: But this Works!
"""    sEuropeanExercise = Application.Run("qlEuropeanExercise", "EuropeanExercise", 43449)  """

Comment: @Ester I don't know what you mean by "don't work", and in any case, you're calling on some 3rd party function/subroutine which you have not provided the code for, so it is impossible to say what might be the problem.

Comment: FDDividendAmericanEngine...How to call this function? Have a look on this link! http://www.quanttools.com/HTMLHelp/html/CT.06069.htm

Comment: Can you please edit your Answer and let me know how to Call this Function ?

Comment: why don't you ask a new question, since you have a new/separate question now?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no need to repeat a function or sub name when calling it via `Application.Run`, and that isn't what you are seeing. `qlBlackConstantVol` is not the same name as `blackConstantVol` (note the `ql`). In context, `"blackConstantVol"` is simply a string parameter which is being passed to `qlBlackConstantVol`. The fact that this string is similar to the name of the function is irrelevant, and doesn't reflect any constraint on the use of `Application.Run`.

Comment: Is it necessary to pass the arguments as we are doing presently ?

Comment: @Ester You pass whatever arguments you need to pass for the function/sub to do its job. Look at the documentation for `qlBlackConstantVol`. It isn't clear to me why `Application.Run` is being used rather than directly calling the function. You haven't given any relevant context to your question. I can't really speculate on code fragments written by third parties who seem to be using a fourth party add-in.

Comment: Sir, FDDividendAmericanEngine...How to call this function? It is not present in Quantlib Library. Can you please edit your answer and let me know how to call this Function

Comment: I have never heard of that function, so I have no idea how to call it. In any event, if you have another question, please ask it as a new question rather than in the comments to an answer of another question.

Comment: Sir have a look on this Site. http://www.quanttools.com/HTMLHelp/html/CT.06069.htm

Comment: Sir, How do I call a function not present in this list?
List: https://www.quantlib.org/quantlibxl/allfunctions.html

Comment: "How do I call a function not present in this list?" There are infinitely many functions which are not present in that list. If they are VBA functions you call them like any other VBA function. In any event -- comments are meant for clarifications, not for posing new questions.

Comment: Sir can you please answer here? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937338/how-do-i-call-a-function-not-present-in-the-list?noredirect=1#comment88873668_50937338